# If a checkbox is checked, activate a field

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, semantic-ui

I am a beginner and i need some help. In my code I use jQuery and Semantic-ui. I try to activate text input after i checked the checkbox input.

When checkbox is checked class change from `class="ui slider checkbox "` to `class="ui slider checkbox checked"`.
To activate text input I need to change `class="disabled field"` to class="field".

I have looked into the following resources:

- https://semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox.html#/usage
- https://semantic-ui.com/collections/form.html#disabled-field

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title> ASD</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css">
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div class="inline field">
     <div class="ui slider checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" tabindex="0" class="hidden" />
       <label>Imprumutata</label>
     </div>
   </div>
      
   <div class="ui equal width form">
     <div class="disabled field">
       <label>Data</label>
       <input placeholder="Data" type="text" disabled="" tabindex="-1" />
     </div>
   </div>
   <script>
     $('.ui.accordion').accordion();
   </script>
   <script>
     $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
   </script>
   <script>
     $('.ui.checkbox').checkbox();
   </script>
       
       
       
       
   // this is what i tried
   <script>
     if($(".ui.checkbox").is('.ui.checkbox.checked'))
       $(".ui.disabled.field").addClass(".ui.field");  // checked
     else
       $(".ui.disabled.field").addClass(".ui.disabled.field");  // unchecked
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use an id for the div you want to change and use the jQuery id-selector syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> ASD</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="inline field">
 <div class="ui slider checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" tabindex="0" class="hidden" />
   <label>Imprumutata</label>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="ui equal width form">
 <div class="disabled field">
   <label>Data</label>
   <input placeholder="Data" type="text" disabled="" tabindex="-1" />
 </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('.ui.accordion').accordion();
</script>
<script>
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
</script>
<script>
    $('.ui.checkbox').checkbox();
</script>
<script>
    $(".ui.checkbox").click(function () {
        var fieldClass = $(".form .field").attr('class'); 
        if( fieldClass == "disabled field"){
            $(".form .field").attr('class', 'field'); 
        }else{
            $(".form .field").attr('class', 'disabled field'); 
        }
    });
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for late.

Comment: If this solve your problem then accept my answer by clicking the accept button

Comment: I have a little problem. In my code exist field class and your solution also affects that class. 
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FKVOPF6OEHSU

What I want is to manipulat only "Data" (disable field).

Comment: Hi @Lucian, I could not understand your question(your problem) exactly, can you please describe it more clearly for me?

Comment: Okay. I have a form, which has 10 fields, 5 are always active and 5 are inactive, when i click my checkbox must turn on in active fields (the 5 inactive fields) and vice versa. 
The problem is that I do not know how to manipulate these classes from Sematic UI.
Hope it's clear now, I'm sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You're not listening for any changes to the page. You need to wrap that script inside a click event handler or a change event handler.

```
$(".ui.checkbox").click(function () { // or .change
  // Your script
});
```